# Binding property to an element's child using element's name | Angular 5

Tags: angular, data-binding, binding, angular5

I am building an application using Angular 5. I am stuck at the position where I need to bind the property to a variable(an element's name). The code provided below is working, but I am sure this is not the correct way to do it and there is another way.

Case: There are arrow filled(.arrow-fill) and arrow border(.arrow-border) inside the parent container. On click of the container, I need to hide/show the arrows based on certain conditions.

For now, I have given name to the parent using '#', and passing it to the method created in typescript. And there based on the condition, assigning a new property to the element('s name).
Below is an example code of what I have done. There are multiple tabs like these, and they are hardcoded and not using ngFor to generate them.

`<li #liTab2 (click)="checkAndDisplay(liTab1)">`
`<div class="arr arrow-border" *ngIf="liTab.showBorder"></div>`
`<div class="arr arrow-fill" *ngIf="!liTab.showBorder"></div>`
`</li>`

`<li #liTab2 (click)="checkAndDisplay(liTab2)">`
`<div class="arr arrow-border" *ngIf="liTab2.showBorder"></div>`
`<div class="arr arrow-fill" *ngIf="!liTab2.showBorder"></div>`
`</li>`

Now in the typescript, the function is:
`checkAndDisplay(elem) {
  elem.nativeElement.showBorder = !elem.nativeElement.showBorder;
  /*some other functions are also taking place here */
}`

Is there any other way, correct way, to do this here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li (click)="showBorder = !showBorder">
        <div class="arr arrow-border" *ngIf="showBorder">Div 1</div>
        <div class="arr arrow-fill" *ngIf="!showBorder">Div 2</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is another way to do it!

Comment: I have multiple li tags, and also I need to call a method as it is doing multiple things. 
So can you suggest any other answer pls. Thanks

Comment: so you have to use *ngFor for multiple li tag based on your array. `<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let obj of YourData" (click)="obj.showBorder = !obj.showBorder">
        <div class="arr arrow-border" *ngIf="obj.showBorder">Div 1</div>
        <div class="arr arrow-fill" *ngIf="!obj.showBorder">Div 2</div>
    </li>
</ul>`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have updated my question with the new code. But If I will use ngFor to repeat, and I click on any of the li tag, the value of showBorder will change and it will affect all the other li's. Can we restrict it to that particular li tag.

Comment: You ca use this code `<ul>
 <ng-template *ngFor="let obj of YourData">
  <li *ngIf="your-true-condition" (click)="obj.showBorder = !obj.showBorder">
   <div class="arr arrow-border" *ngIf="obj.showBorder">Div 1</div>
   <div class="arr arrow-fill" *ngIf="!obj.showBorder">Div 2</div>
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="your-false-condition">
   <div class="arr arrow-border" *ngIf="obj.showBorder">Div 1</div>
   <div class="arr arrow-fill" *ngIf="!obj.showBorder">Div 2</div>
  </li>
 </ng-template>
</ul>`

Comment: Ok. It works, may be not what I am looking for. But is it a good approach to assign a new key-value to an object which does not exists?